# Thevenin equivalent with mutual inductance

Tags: thevenin, norton, mutual-inductance

I was practicing for the exam I found a problem in the book as follow :

[image: the question]

I want to find the voltage Vth so here is what I did :
[image: my solution]

When finding the Vth I didn't ignore the dependant voltage source in the second loop

But I found a solution on the internet he ignored it and got different answer due to that.

Who is right now?

Thank you all

Comment: I would personally replace the transformer by a perfect transformer affected by a turns ratio and a leakage inductance. Did you try to run a quick simulation to see if results match what you've found?

Comment: I don't know how to add mutual inductance and tell me about the way you prefer doing it @VerbalKint

Comment: Using simulation and Mathcad, I obtained an output voltage of 638.65 V and a phase of 9.75°, very close to what you calculated.

Answer (score 1):

By using the equivalent circuit of the two coupled inductances, the calculation is simplified. See the drawing:

[image]